# QPaintEvent disables QLineEdit when painting on stackedWidget - PyQt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I was trying to draw a diagram on one of my pages on stacked widget in my GUI. 
I have a painter class like this:

```
class Painter(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Painter, self).__init__()

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        self.draw_lines(qp)

    def draw_lines(self, qp):
        pen = QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.blue, 2, QtCore.Qt.SolidLine)  # draw graph
        qp.setPen(pen)
        qp.drawLine(80, 209, 150, 209)
        qp.drawLine(150, 209, 220, 60)
        qp.drawLine(430, 60, 500, 209)  
        qp.drawLine(500, 209, 570, 209) 
        qp.drawLine(220, 60, 430, 60)
```

Then I have a class with one of the pages on my stacked widget where I call Painter class:

```
# create page 2
self.page_2 = QtGui.QWidget()
self.main_layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
self.page_2.setLayout(self.main_layout)

# create  group box
self.group_box = QtGui.QGroupBox(self.page_2)

# add plot diagram
self.PaintPanel = diagram.Painter()
self.PaintPanel.close()
self.main_layout.addWidget(self.PaintPanel, 0, 0)

# set text field
self.text = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.group_box)
self.text.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 330, 41, 21))

self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_2)
```

My problem is that the QLineEdit becomes non active (blocked/frozen?) when I add Painter class widget. Without this, the QLineEdit works fine. I wonder why is that and how to fix this? Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Painter is a QWidget, and it's sitting on top of your QLineEdit, so the Painter gets all of the mouse events. If you want to paint on top of the QLineEdit, I'd suggest subclassing QLineEdit and overriding its paint method.

I was also thinking you could make Painter an event filter instead of a QWidget and intercept your QLineEdit paint events, but I believe that will have the Painter paint first, and then the QLineEdit. That's probably not what you want.

Comment: Alright I get it now. Thank you so much,   I understand where my error is.  So I want it to be like: a diagram painted by the Painter class on top of the page (for example painted on a QFrame or something like this) and a QLineEdit at the bottom of the page so that my diagram will not be sitting on QLineEdit anymore.  Do you know how can I archive that?  Any hint will be helpful thanks :)

Comment: I figured it out now. Thank you for your help @goug